# count matches based on list of values in a cell

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, countif

This seems like it should be simple but after googling for hours and trying many different approaches I'm stumped.

I have a table of values containing single and two digit numbers, and a cell containing the list of values to be counted. This list of values is separated by spaces and can be any length.

The first version of this I did worked fine because I was only using single digit numbers in the table. This is the formula I used: `=countIf(arrayFormula(regexMatch(<table>, substitute(<cell>, " ", "|"))), TRUE)`

So in my list cell I can put `2 4 6` and all the cells containing those numbers will be counted.

For the second version I need to able to put `3 12` and make sure values like 2 and 13 would not be counted.

I would like to avoid using VBA since I want this to work in sheets, number, excel, etc.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(B:B&"", "^"&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "$|^")&"$")), TRUE)
```

[image]